# unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am completing a codeusing the bayesian classifier using the gaussian distribution.
In some part of the code as you can see I need to define a dictionary called meanDict for calculating the mean of parameters X1 and X2 and then use the same calculateMeanDict function to calulate the var in the calculate var function.
However, after getting to the `var = np.mean((X-meanDict[y])^2)` part of the code, I receive a **TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' error.**
Can anybody please help me on this?

```
# !!! Must Not Change the Imports !!!
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Dict

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler

from TicToc import timing, Timer


def loadDataset(filepath='Data/PokemonUnivariate.csv', labelCol='type1') -> (np.ndarray, np.ndarray, LabelEncoder):
    """
    !!! Must Not Change the Content !!!
    This function is used to load dataset
    Data will be scaled from 0 to 1
    :param filepath: csv file path
    :param labelCol: column name
    :return: X: ndarray, y: ndarray, labelEncoder
    """
    data = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    y = data[labelCol].values
    labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
    y = labelEncoder.fit_transform(y)
    X = data.drop(columns=[labelCol]).values
    X = np.nan_to_num(X)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
    return X, y, labelEncoder


class LinearClassifier(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """!!! Must Not Change the Content !!!"""
        self.X = None
        self.y = None
        self.w = 0
        self.b = 0

    def name(self) -> str:
        """!!! Must Not Change the Content !!!"""
        return self.__class__.__name__

    def sigmoid(self, X, w=None, b=None):
        """
        !!! Must Not Change the Content !!!
        Sigmoid function
        :param X: X
        :param w: weight
        :param b: bias
        :return: sigmoid(wx + b)
        """
        w, b = self.w if w is None else w, self.b if b is None else b
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(w * X + b)))

    def fit(self, X, y):
        """!!! Must Not Change the Content !!!"""
        raise NotImplementedError

    def predictSample(self, x) -> int:
        """
        ToDo: Implement This Function
        Predict a label of given x
        If sigmoid(x) is greater than 0.5, then the label is 1; otherwise the label is 0
        :param x: a sample
        :return: a label
        """
        if sigmoid(X, w, b) > 0.5:
            label = 1
        else:
            label = 0
        return label

    def predict(self, X):
        """
        !!! Must Not Change the Content !!!
        Predict the labels of given X
        If sigmoid(x) is greater than 0.5, then the label is 1; otherwise the label is 0
        """
        return np.apply_along_axis(self.predictSample, axis=1, arr=X)


class UnivariateGaussianDiscriminantAnalysisClassifier(LinearClassifier):
    """
    Univariate Gaussian Classifier
    Univariate & Binary Class
    """
    @staticmethod
    def lnPrior(X1, X2):
        """
        !!! Must Not Change the Content !!!
        Calculate the ln P(C1) and ln P(C2)
        :param X1: X with C1 label
        :param X2: X with C2 label
        :return (ln P(C1), ln P(C2))
        """
        (nX1, _), (nX2, _) = X1.shape, X2.shape
        return np.log(nX1 / (nX1 + nX2)), np.log(nX2 / (nX1 + nX2))

    @staticmethod
    def calculateMeanDict(X1, X2) -> Dict[int, float]:
        """
        ToDo: Implement This Function
        This function should return a diction,
        which 0: mean X1, and 1: mean X2
        :param X1: ndarray
        :param X2: ndarray
        :return: mean dict
        """
        meanDict = dict(mean_X1= np.mean(X1), mean_X2= np.mean(X2))
        return meanDict

    @staticmethod
    def calculateVar(meanDict, X, y) -> float:
        """
        ToDo: Implement This Function
        This function calculates the variance of X
        var = mean (xi-meanDict[yi])^2
        :param meanDict: 0: mean X1, and 1: mean X2
        :param X: X
        :param y: y
        :return: var
        """
        var = meanDict['mean_X1']
        #var = np.mean((X-meanDict[y])^2)
        return var

    @staticmethod
    def calculateW(meanDict, var) -> float:
        """
        ToDo: Implement This Function
        Calculate w. w=(mean2-mean1)/var
        :param meanDict: 0: mean X1, and 1: mean X2
        :param var: variance
        :return: w
        """
        w = (meanDict['mean_X1'] - meanDict['mean_X2'])/var^2
        return w

    @staticmethod
    def calculateB(meanDict, var, lnPrior1, lnPrior2) -> float:
        """
        ToDo: Implement This Function
        calculate b. b=(mean1^2-mean2^2)/(2*var) + ln(P(C2)) - ln(P(C1))
        :param meanDict: 0: mean X1, and 1: mean X2
        :param var: variance
        :param lnPrior1: ln(P(C1))
        :param lnPrior2: ln(P(C2))
        :return: b
        """
        b = ((meanDict['mean X1'])^2 -(meanDict['mean X2'])^2/(2*var^2)) + lnPrior2 - lnPrior1

    def fit(self, X, y):
        """
        !!! Must Not Change the Content !!!
        Train the Univariate Gaussian Classifier
        :param X: shape (N Samples, 1)
        :param y: shape (1, N Samples)
        """
        self.X, self.y = X, y
        nX, _ = X.shape
        X1 = np.array([x1 for x1, y1 in zip(X, y) if y1 == 0])
        X2 = np.array([x2 for x2, y2 in zip(X, y) if y2 == 1])
        lnPrior1, lnPrior2 = self.lnPrior(X1, X2)
        meanDict = self.calculateMeanDict(X1, X2)
        var = self.calculateVar(meanDict, X, y)
        self.w = self.calculateW(meanDict, var)
        self.b = self.calculateB(meanDict, var, lnPrior1, lnPrior2)
        return self


@timing
def main():
    """
    !!! Must Not Change the Content !!!
    """
    randomState = 0
    resultFolder = Path('Data/')

    with Timer('Data Loaded'):
        X, y, _ = loadDataset()
        XTrain, XTest, yTrain, yTest = \
            train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=randomState)
        print(f'Training Set Length: {XTrain.shape[0]}\n'
              f'Testing Set Length: {XTest.shape[0]}')
    classifiers = [UnivariateGaussianDiscriminantAnalysisClassifier()]
    for classifier in classifiers:
        with Timer(f'{classifier.name()} Trained'):
            classifier.fit(XTrain, yTrain)
        with Timer(f'{classifier.name()} Tested'):
            yPredicted = classifier.predict(XTest)
        with Timer(f'{classifier.name()} Results Saved'):
            resultsCsv = pd.DataFrame()
            resultsCsv['yPredicted'] = yPredicted
            resultsCsv['yTrue'] = yTest
            resultsCsvPath = resultFolder / f'{classifier.name()}Results.csv'
            resultsCsv.to_csv(resultsCsvPath, index=False)

            resultsStr = f'{classification_report(yTest, yPredicted, digits=5)}\n' \
                         f'{classifier.name()}: w={classifier.w}; b={classifier.b}'
            resultsTxtPath = resultFolder / f'{classifier.name()}Results.txt'
            with open(resultsTxtPath, 'w') as resultsTxtFile:
                resultsTxtFile.write(resultsStr)
            print(resultsStr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(timerPrefix='Total Time Costs: ', timerBeep=False)
```

Comment: what are X1 and X2? Please specify or give an appropriate example of how they would look. I think it has something to do with the shape of array X1 and X2 due to the n-dimensionality factor being given to numpy for mean. Also try using `np.mean(list(X1))`

Comment: So I put the complete code may be you could understand better about it. I am asked to do it using a dictionary

Comment: I editted the code in the question]

Comment: The error says you can't use an array as a dictionary key.  If it occurs in `meanDict[y]`, my guess is `y` an array.

Comment: @hpaulj It is perfectly fine how he has implemented it.

Comment: @JalalKuzkov Please mention the dimensionality of X1 and X2. Give an estimate of what X1 and X2 looks like by calling `print(X1.shape)` and `print(X2.shape)`

Comment: @RaghavGupta, it's hard to tell what `y` is at that point.  WIthout traceback, and multiple layers of functions it's hard to trace the variables and their type.

Comment: @hpaulj So X1 and X2 are two instances from my training dataset with 175 elements. So shape of X1 is (82,1) and shape of X2 is (93,1). Also I have attached as much information I have about the y in the image (please see the link): https://ibb.co/HLcHy3x

Comment: Are we still dealing with the hashing error?  The problem line (I think) is commented out.

Comment: Yes, I commented it out to test what the problem is. So disregard the line above the commented line

Comment: If I read the code right, I can trance the problem `y` back to `y_train`, which I am guessing is an array of labels, strings.  If that's the case, `meanDict[y[0]` might work, using the first string in that array